# Searching for animations

Tags: support, search, images

I spend most of my time in Stack Exchange in either Stack Overflow or [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). Over a number of years I have seen numerous beautiful animations -- mainly GIF animations I think -- that make sometimes quite subtle points about statistical analysis crystal clear and intuitively obvious.

Several related examples are what it means that regression projects y into the column space of x, the difference between regressing x on y and regressing y on x, and how least-angle regression works. I remember seeing animations for each of these, at least one of which involved rotating the regression line and showing how the squared errors changed.

I wanted to explain some of these things to a mathematically unsophisticated, but visually gifted friend, and spent a couple of hours looking for them, but I was unable to find any of them. Is there a way of searching for posts that include animations, GIF images or otherwise, that do not include the words "GIF" or "animation"?

Comment: If it's an actual .gif file, then you might try using the search term `url:.gif`, which will look for ".gif" in URLs.

Comment: I know it's not all that helpful now, but being able to find things again that were of interest to you is one of the reasons for bookmarks. If you find something interesting, you might want to bookmark it. You browser almost certainly has the ability to use multiple different folders, so you could have a bookmark folder like Stack Exchange ➞ Cross Validated ➞ interesting. An alternative that might work currently is to look through your browser's history, which may have a record of the questions you visited where you saw these, perhaps which a title that jogs you memory.